# How to use mathematical notation or engineering notation in certain columns of a kableExtra table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, notation, kable, kableextra

One can apply [docxtools::format_engr()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docxtools/vignettes/numbers-in-engineering-format.html) to a table to switch from computer notation to engineering notation.

[image: NotationTypes]
(Source: [docxtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docxtools/vignettes/numbers-in-engineering-format.html))

Applying `docxtools::format_engr()` to a df changes all columns to engineering notation.

1. How to apply the function only to some columns of a df?
2. Is there an equivalent function for mathematical notation?

For the toy example below, the idea would be to get the `p_Pa` column in engineering/mathematical notation, while all other columns remain the same.

### MWE

#### Table as desired only missing the `p_Pa` column in engineering notation

```
library(docxtools)
density2 <- density
density2$density <- density2$density*1000
kable(density2, digits = 2)
```

[image: GOAL]

#### Apply formatting: "all" columns change to engineering notation

```
# Apply formatting:
density_engr <- density2 %>%
  docxtools::format_engr()
kable(density_engr)
```

[image: All get exponentiated]

Passing `sigdig()` to `docxtools::format_engr()` (e.g., sth. like "sigdig = c(0,0,2,3,2,3)") to define how to format which column does not help here.
Engineering notation is still applied to ALL columns, only with differing numbers of digits.

The idea is to include the df as `kableExtra` table in an `R markdown` report compiled with `knitr` both to PDF and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataframe that contains only the columns you want formatted, format that, and then assign it into place in the original.  For example, starting with your `density2`:

```
density_engr <- density2        # no formatting yet
do_format <- c("T_K", "p_Pa")   # which columns to format?
density_engr[do_format] <- docxtools::format_engr(density_engr[do_format])
```

There are other ways to do the indexing besides `density_engr[do_format]`, but be careful:  you want to make sure you get a dataframe as the result, you don't want to extract a column.